# Command to comment out a line of text and append a modification on the next line

Tags: replace, sed, command-line

Take this text file:

```
# Existing comment

#some already_commented_out line

some target line
```

And produce this:

```
# Existing comment

#some already_commented_out line

#some target line
some modified line
```

I can do this using two separate sed commands:

```
sed -i -r 's/^[^#].*target.*$/#&\n&/' textfile
sed -i -r '/^[^#].*target/{s/target/modified/}' textfile
```

Is there a way to combine them into a single command? Are there better ways to do this using other sed commands (such as append)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -i '/\(.*\)target/{h;G;s//#\1 modified/}' textfile
```

When `target` is found, `h` holds the line and `G` appends it to the pattern space(the line is now duplicated).

The `s` command replaces the last occurrence of `target` with `modified`.

Answer (score 0):

In your simple case it can be achieved with the following `sed` command:

```
sed -i -r 's/^([^#]*)(target)(.*)$/#\1\2\3\n\1modified\3/g' testfile
```

---

`\1`, `\2`, `\3` are the first, second and third captured group respectively

---

`cat testfile` output:

```
# Existing comment

#some already_commented_out line

#some target line
some modified line
```

Comment: But what if group capturing is also used in a search pattern, e.g. `tar(get)+`? I don't know in advance how many such groups are used because the pattern is supplied from the outside. Is there a way to refer to the last matched group at least?